# using ConcurrentStack

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack

I need to use the stack data structure to save strings. But this stack will be accessed from multiple threads. So my question is, how do I use the ConcurrentStack to add data from multiple threads?

Comment: Did you try searching for .NET4 concurrent stack??  e.g. http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/02/01/NET-40-and-System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentStack.aspx

Comment: 1. Create a [ConcurrentStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx) instance. 2. Create multiple threads. 3. Call the Push method from any thread on the ConcurrentStack instance. Which part do you need help with?

Comment: @Hightechrider, i did a search but i didnt find anything for my needs as a good example. But thanks for your link!

Comment: @dtb - possibly just reassurance. Multithreading is still out of scope or new and strange for many developers.

Comment: @dtb, thats all i needed to know! wasn't sure if i needed to lock anything or not, however i did read it was thread-safe. but i couldn't find a good example that fits my needs.

Comment: A quick question, is there an equivalent voor Queue too? Which is thread safe? I can't find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Congratulations, you have chosen the correct container for multihreaded usage.  The entire class is thread-safe, and recommended for your scenario, so just party on using `Push` or `PushRange` as appropriate.

The ranges example code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx) uses parallelization to demonstrate multithreaded operation.

Comment: @Yustme, check also Parallel Computing Technical Articles http://bit.ly/aSaTIV, specifically http://bit.ly/8XJkj8 and Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4 http://bit.ly/acDjRm

Answer (score 10):

You have received some pretty good answers so far. Let me provide some useful information regarding its design to help you better understand how it can be used. Notice that there is no `Pop` method. That is because the designers wanted to prevent you from doing the following unsafe sequence of operations. It is unsafe because the sequence of calls to the `Count` property and hypothetical `Pop` method are not atomic despite the collection being billed as thread-safe.

```
while (stack.Count > 0)
{
  stack.Pop();
}
```

To reconcile this common use case the designers used the `TryPop` method instead. This essentially allows you to rewrite the above like the following. This time the code is safe.

```
object item;
while (stack.TryPop(out item))
{
  // Do something with the item here.
}
```

A corollary to my first example exists with the `Push` method as well. The following code (which is legal this time) is also unsafe.

```
if (stack.Count < MAX_ITEMS)
{
  stack.Push(...);
}
```

The later example is not as common a use case as the former and that is probably why the designers did not add the [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)-like equivalent operation `TryPush`. Perhaps in a future release that will be made available to us.

Comment: For the last example, to create a maximum size that is thread-safe, there is the BlockingCollection<T> class for .NET 4.0 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

You create your `ConcurrentStack<string>`, and make sure all of the threads have a reference to it.

The threads would then just call [Push](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287104.aspx) to add strings:

```
theStack.Push("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding values to a `ConcurrentStack` from multiple threads is fairly straight forward.  Just make a reference to the stack available and call `Push` from whichever thread needs to add data.  No special locking is needed here as the collection is designed to be used from multiple threads in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

One on thread use:

```
_stack.Push(obj);
```

On another thread use:

```
MyObj obj;    
if (_stack.TryPop(out obj))
    UseObj(obj);
```

I recommend reading [this MSDN blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324080122/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/06/18/8614596.aspx).